# Polymorphic variable in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, polymorphism

Let's say I have a class named `Parent` and two derived classes called `Child1` and `Child2`.

```
@interface Parent :  NSObject {
  NSString *fooVariable;
  -(void)foo; 
}
@end

@interface Child1 :  Parent {
-(void)bar1;
}
@end

@interface Child2 :  Parent {
-(void)bar2;
}
@end
```

Now imagine I have a method called `foo` and in some cases I want to pass it as a parameter an instance of `Child1` and in some other cases an instance of `Child2`. Depending on the class type I want to call either method `bar1` or `bar2`.

How can I achieve this in Objective-c?

**What I've tried:**

I decided to use the following signature and implementation:

```
-(void)fooWithObject:(Parent *)instance{
    if ([instance isKindOfClass:[Child1 class]]){
        [instance bar1];
    }
    else{
        [instance bar2];
    }
}
```

So now I can do this:

```
Parent *instance = [[Child1 alloc] init];

//This call is supposed to lead to an invocation of bar1 inside the foo method
[self fooWithObject:instance]

instance = [[Child2 alloc] init];
//This call is supposed to lead to an invocation of bar2 inside the foo method
[self fooWithObject:instance]
```

Unfortunately, when I try to compile my code the compiler complains that there's is no method bar1 (or bar2) declared in my Parent's interface.

According to a some tutorials online you can do the following, so theoretically my approach should work:

```
NSArray *anotherArray = [NSMutableArray array];
// This mutable-only method call is valid but
// produces a compile-time warning
[anotherArray addObject:@"Hello World"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there.  After the type check, you can safely cast and make the compiler happy, too:

```
-(void)fooWithObject:(Parent *)instance {

    if ([instance isKindOfClass:[Child1 self]]) {
        Child1 *child1Instance = (Child1 *)instance;
        [child1Instance bar1];
    } else {
        Child2 *child2Instance = (Child2 *)instance;
        [child2Instance bar2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this something that you recommend doing? Is it good practice?

Comment: Yes.  It's good for many reasons, especially in that it operates at virtually no cost (just an assignment) makes the code clear, and allows the compiler to check your code for safety.

Comment: Perfectly good practice, if you need to do something like this.  If it works out it's better, though, to just have the method `bar` defined in all three classes, so you don't need to test which class you have.

Comment: Ok. Since another member recommended this method I'll give it a go. Thanks for your comments. What do you think about selectors as an alternative?

Comment: It will make the compiler happy, but more by hiding type information from it.  As a result, you get past the warning, but lose the benefit of knowing the type at compile time.  I also like defining the method in the parent and children... that seeming right depends more on the semantics of the classes and the method.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to declare a bar function in the Parent and the children. Then the appropriate bar function will be called depending on the class passed.  You could use the isKindOfClass function, but that defeats the beauty of inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. You are right. But what if it's counter-intuitive to add a bar function in the Parent class? Imagine if the Parent class is a Shape class and the children are Circle and Square. I could have a setHeight method in Square but not in Circle.

Comment: Yes, that is a good point, like the conundrum as to whether a square should extend a rectangle or the other way round. Neither feels right. If the inheritance hierarchy feels wrong then maybe the design should change.

Comment: @GeorgeEracleous - Yes, there are cases where the single method name does not "fit" the concepts well, in which case you can use what you originally came up with.  It's not black-and-white -- there are many subtle "shades" when doing this sort of stuff.

Comment: @GeorgeEracleous, David is right anyway. In the case that you pointed out in your question, having some (quasi abstract - I know there is not abstract in ObjC but that is what I mean) method `bar` in `Parent`, which is not really implemented in `Parent` (it has to be implemented in Parent in ObjC but the implementation may only be just formal.) Your second situation (taken from your comment here) is different. In that case you still could but probably won't implement bar in Parent but in one of its subclasses. If you really need it in some subclasses only, then you may want to use a protocol.

Answer (score 3):

If you think you need to do this (and you have to ask), you're not using polymorphism right.  In this particular situation, you should override `fooWithObject:` in both children and call the appropriate method for that instance. But it sounds like you may have deeper problems with your class structure.

Comment: So maybe in this case polymorphism is not the way to go? Is there a more suitable pattern I could use?

Comment: You really haven't given enough information about the underlying problem and structure to say one way or another. Polymorphism is probably a good option, but if you keep running into problems like this you might want to rethink how your class hierarchy is structured.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to (a) name the two `bar` methods to be the same; and (b) either define a `bar` function for `Parent`, or use a protocol:

```
@protocol Bar <NSObject>
- (void)bar;
@end

@interface Parent : NSObject {
  NSString *fooVariable;
}
-(void)foo; 
@end

@interface Child1 :  Parent <Bar>
@end

@interface Child2 :  Parent <Bar>
@end
```

And then have a method:

```
-(void)fooWithObject:(id<Bar>)instance {
    [instance bar];
}
```

If you really needed `bar1` and `bar2` to be completely different names (this is a point where really abstract method names make the question less clear), then you could do something like:

```
@interface Parent : NSObject {
  NSString *fooVariable;
}
-(void)foo; 
@end

@interface Child1 :  Parent
- (void)bar1;
@end

@interface Child2 :  Parent
- (void)bar2;
@end
```

And then,

```
-(void)fooWithObject:(Parent *)instance {
    if ([instance isKindOfClass:[Child1 class]]) {
        [(Child1 *)instance bar1];
    }
    else if ([instance isKindOfClass:[Child1 class]]) {
        [(Child2 *)instance bar2];
    }
}
```

Or

```
-(void)fooWithObject:(Parent *)instance {
    if ([instance respondsToSelector:@selector(bar1)]) {
        [(Child1 *)instance bar1];
    }
    else if ([instance respondsToSelector:@selector(bar2)] {
        [(Child2 *)instance bar2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. The first approach I don't think it'll work for me since like you mentioned I want two different methods bar1 and bar2. I'll try to give a more concrete example to clarify why. Imagine if the Parent class is a Shape class and the children are Circle and Square. I could have a setHeight method in Square but not in Circle. For Circle I'd like to have a setRadius method.

Now about the second suggestion the first approach with typecasting is it a good practice?

Comment: @GeorgeEracleous casting is a practice that should be used judiciously but when done within the context of a runtime check like `isKindOfClass`, it's fine. (IMHO, casts are often code-smell for deeper design flaws, but in some cases it's fine.) Whether you do this casting in-line, like here, or with a variable assignment, like what danh suggested, it just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @GeorgeEracleous Considering your example, I'd rather see a method, `resizeWithRect` or something like that. A parent class has no business delving into the specifics of its children.